# Embedding plotly output in R markdown

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown, plotly

There is a [blog entry](http://hianalytics.github.io/plotly/how-to-use-plot.ly-and-ggplotly-with-R-Markdown/) which describes embedding from the plotly API for R into R markdown. I just used the code to create the iframe for an html document

When I have the prieview in R studio there is no error message and the iframe is created in the html document. However, it is just empty. Apparently it does not load the content somehow. I did not create the plot in the R API beforehand (but that should not matter as this is just embedding a picture into html) isn't it?

My code in r markdown as it is is  currently

````
```{r}
library("knitr")
library("devtools")
url<-"https://plot.ly/~etpinard/251"
plotly_iframe <- paste("<iframe scrolling='no' seamless='seamless' src='", url, 
    "/800/600' width='800' height='600'></iframe>", sep = "")

```
`r I(plotly_iframe)`
````

Answer (score 7):

We had this same issue the first time we published an RPub. [Here](http://rpubs.com/Msunds/24548) is your code in a published RPub.

Once it's published at RPubs.com rather than in preview, the graphs *should* show up. You can test it by using the "open in browser" option in RPubs:

[image: RPub]

A note. I changed `height` to 800 and `width` to 650, as that graph is a bit tall. I also added a `<center>` tag to place it in the center of the published version.

Plotly also has a target URL for embedding. In this case, it's https://plot.ly/~etpinard/251.embed. RPubs doesn't seem to like that though. You also might play around with `borderwidth` to see if you can turn off the border.

That's all to say: the graphs won't show up in the preview. I believe this is a browser limitation, as RStudio doesn't allow for publishing live web content (yet).

If you're interested and would like some example code, [here is the source](https://gist.github.com/sckott/10991885) for [a blog post](http://ropensci.org/blog/2014/04/17/plotly/) that has embedded Plotly and ggplot2 plots. Hope this helps! Disclosure: I work for Plotly.

**Update: Aug. 21, 2015**

Head to the Plotly documentation to see the [R Markdown](https://plot.ly/r/knitr/) version of this answer. Printing plotly objects in the R console creates an online figure. For example:

```
p <- plot_ly(economics, x = date, y = uempmed, filename="r-docs/knitr-example")
```

If you are using knitr/R Markdown with HTML output, printing the `plotly` object will now embed the plot in the HTML as an iframe. If you are writing a document with R Markdown, simply printing `p` will embed the plot.

You can also set the width and the height of the plot with width and height code chunk parameters. For example: {r, height=800} sets the height.

If you are using [Plotly Offline with R Studio](https://plot.ly/r/offline/), then printing the plotly object in knitr will also include the necessary plotly.js files to draw the graph: the graph is rendered locally inside the document.

To convert the knitr document to a standalone HTML file, use `knitr::knit` and `markdown::markdownToHTML`. For example:

```
knitr::knit('plotly-report.Rmd', 'plotly-report.md')
markdown::markdownToHTML('plotly-report.md', 'plotly-report.html')
```

Comment: `knitr` documentation states the the image size specified in the chunk header is in inches regardless of whether the graphic is a `plotly` graph or not.  Can you comment on that?

Comment: If I have a function such as `make_plotly()` that runs your `p <- plot_ly(...)` command and performs `return(p)`, the plot appears in the RMarkdown document. However, if I call `make_plotly()` from within another function such as `run_workflow()`, then the plot no longer appears, even when I `print` it.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add a ".embed?width=550&height=550" after my url to make it work. See below

````
```{r}
library("knitr")
library("devtools")
url<-"https://plot.ly/yourplothere.embed?width=550&height=550" 
plotly_iframe <- paste("<center><iframe scrolling='no' seamless='seamless' style='border:none' src='", url, 
    "/800/1200' width='800' height='1200'></iframe><center>", sep = "")

```
`r I(plotly_iframe)`
````