# How do I embed surface plots in html documents using knitr and plotly?

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I think the R Markdown (Rmd) code below should produce a html document with a surface plot embedded in it.

````
```{r, plotly=TRUE}
library(plotly)
py <- plotly()

x_vec = c(seq(-5, 4.9, 0.1))
x_matrix = matrix(c(x_vec), nrow = 100, ncol = 1)
y_matrix = matrix(c(x_vec), nrow = 1, ncol = 100)

data <- list(
  x = x_vec,
  y = x_vec,
  z = matrix(c(cos(x_matrix %*% y_matrix) + sin(x_matrix %*% y_matrix)), nrow = 100, ncol = 100),
  type = "surface")

layout <- list(
  title = "Waaaves in r",
  scene = list(bgcolor = "rgb(244, 244, 248)"))

    response <- py$plotly(data, session="knitr",
                          kwargs = list(
                            layout = layout,
                            world_readable=FALSE,
                            filename = "waves example",
                            fileopt = "overwrite"))

```
````

The document creates an output with the code embdedded, but there is no plot.  Just an error message saying,

"Uh oh, an error occured on the server."

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Did you try without the plotly option? Or better, what have you tried to avoid it?

Comment: Does the solution in this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186022/embedding-plotly-output-in-r-markdown) work (publishing the document)?

Comment: @Llopis If I remove the argument session="knitr" then there is no error message.  However the figure is not included in the html document.

Comment: @Llopis If I use the py$ggplotly method instead of py$plotly then it works and the plot is included in the html document.  (I used a different data-set to test this.)

Comment: @Mateo the solution you posted works fine.  However it is a bit cumbersome when all I want to do is to look at surface plots as part of some exploratory data analysis.

Comment: It seems the problem it is solved using `py$ggplotly` or is it still unsolved?

Comment: The problem with the py$ggplotly solution is that ggplotly does not produce surface plots (as far as I am aware).  It is a different plotting function / method that produces different types of plots from the plotly function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `py$plotly()`, run `py$irplot()` (without the `session="knitr"` argument). The latter works with the `py$ggplotly()` method, not the `py$plotly()` one.