# Shot of a 3d Plot from Plotly in Rmarkdown compiled to PDF

Tags: pdf, rstudio, r-markdown, plotly

This is surprisingly difficult to do.  I have already seen:

https://plot.ly/r/knitr/

[Plotly as png in knitr/rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268152/plotly-as-png-in-knitr-rmarkdown)

[Embedding plotly output in R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186022/embedding-plotly-output-in-r-markdown?rq=1)

None of these solve the issue and seem to be outdated.  Anyone currently doing this or should I abandon the plotly package?

EDIT:

Looking some more, apparently THIS is true from:

https://community.plot.ly/t/use-plotly-offline-to-save-chart-as-image-file/408/6

```
contacting plotly support resulted in:

community members may only export to PNGs Other formats are
available with the profession plan: https://plot.ly/products/cloud/113

At the moment it is not possible to programatically export an image while using offline, i.e. confirming @jpp

You do have the option to use the camera icon in the mode bar on hover. This worked for me using plotly offline 1.9.3 and chrome, but not Firefox @thauta
```

Comment: See my answer here -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/42684063/1583084

Comment: @Carson In the meanwhile version ‘4.7.1.9000’ your solution is not working anymore, please confirm

Comment: @jaySf fixed, thx